# Personalizar mensagem de erro

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, jpa

Forcei um erro no meu sistema que contém a seguinte mensagem:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement

É uma violação de constraint. Como posso personalizar para exibir uma mensagem persoanlizada exemplo: Atenção: Este ***nome*** já existe no banco de dados.

Eu até criei uma classe para Mensagens e tem este método:

```
public static void erro(String mensagem) {

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, mensagem, "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messagePanel", msg);


    }
```

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem que tratar essa exceção.

```
try {
    cadastrar();
} catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
    erro("Este nome já existe no banco de dados");
    // e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Da uma lida sobre Exceptions, pois é disso que você precisa. [Esse link pode ajudar.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: Posso colocar mais de um tratamento no mesmo catch? Uma vez que podem ocorrer diversos tipos de erro.

Comment: @Douglas Você pode colocar outros tipos de Exception no catch, podendo tratar cada tipo de Exception  de um jeito, ou a Exception comumente usada.

Comment: @Douglas Como o Matheus disse, sim, você pode. Quantas e qualquer uma que você quiser, acredito.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode identificar a Exception `ConstraintViolationException` em um `catch` e personalizar o retorno de uma mensagem para esse erro.

```
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: E como coloco a mensagem que eu quero?